# QMouseEvent::localPos() and high DPI display (Mac Retina)

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside2

Using Qt 5.12, Python 3, PySide2, MacOS.

In the `mouseMoveEvent` handler, `QMouseEvent::localPos()` returns a `QPointF` but only with integer-accuracy: Digits after the decimal point are always zero.

This means that slightly different mouse positions yield events with exactly the same numerical values for the position.

I expect when I move the mouse to slightly different positions something like:

event1: `(4.00, 8.00)`

event2: `(4.50, 8.00)`

but I get

event1: `(4.00, 8.00)`

event2: `(4.00, 8.00)`

How can I distinguish mouse events at only slightly different positions on high DPI displays like Apple Retina?

Answer (score 0):

After test, `QMouseEvent::windowPos()` `QMouseEvent::screenPos()` return float-accuracy.

Therefore, we could get the `localPos` through `mapTo(mainWindow, , QPoint(0, 0))`.

### Code

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
  ...
  MainWindow *getMainWindow() const { return mainWindow; }
  void setMainWindow(MainWindow *win) { mainWindow = win; }

protected:
  void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
  {
    auto pos = event->windowPos();
    pos -= mapTo(getMainWindow(), QPoint(0, 0));
    qDebug() << event->localPos() << pos;
  }

private:
  MainWindow *mainWindow;
}
```

### Result

```
QPointF(2,0) QPointF(2.46875,-0.179688)
QPointF(3,0) QPointF(3.17188,0.171875)
QPointF(3,0) QPointF(3.49609,0.496094)
QPointF(4,1) QPointF(4.19922,0.847656)
QPointF(5,1) QPointF(4.52344,1.17188)
QPointF(5,1) QPointF(4.84766,1.49609)
QPointF(5,2) QPointF(5.17188,1.82031)
QPointF(5,2) QPointF(5.49609,2.14453)
QPointF(6,2) QPointF(5.82031,2.46875)
QPointF(6,3) QPointF(6.14453,2.79297)
QPointF(6,3) QPointF(6.46875,3.11719)
QPointF(7,3) QPointF(6.79297,3.44141)
QPointF(7,4) QPointF(7.11719,3.76563)
QPointF(7,4) QPointF(7.44141,3.76563)
QPointF(8,4) QPointF(7.76563,4.08984)
QPointF(8,4) QPointF(8.08984,4.41406)
QPointF(9,5) QPointF(8.79297,4.76563)
QPointF(9,5) QPointF(9.11719,5.08984)
QPointF(9,5) QPointF(9.44141,5.41406)
QPointF(10,6) QPointF(10.1445,6.11719)
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. It could mean that the issue is just in the PySide2 Python bindings.